# How do I group expressions in NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate

How can I group sets of expressions in NHibernate?  For example, I want to filter my query like so:

```
(ShowOnDate IS NULL OR ShowOnDate <= GETDATE()) AND (ExpirationDate IS NULL OR ExpirationDate >= GETDATE())
```

I can add the 4 criterions separately, but I can't figure out how to emulate the paranthesis grouping.  Thanks!

EDITED to show my final solution:

```
            result = this.Session.CreateCriteria<Model.News>()
                .Add(Expression.IsNull("ExpirationDate") || Expression.Gt("ExpirationDate", DateTime.Now.Date))
                .Add(Expression.IsNull("ShowOnDate") || Expression.Le("ShowOnDate", DateTime.Now.Date))
                .AddOrder(new Order("SubmittedDate", true))
                .List<Model.News>();
```

Comment: Its not clear whether this question relates to HQL or the Criteria API. Nonetheless I've answered from the Criteria point of view in case it is of some use.

Comment: I meant Criteria... thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Criteria API provides operator overloads for || and && allowing you to combine your criteria like this:

```
criteria.Add(
    (Restrictions.IsNull("ShowOnDate")
        || Restrictions.Le("ShowOnDate", DateTime.Now))
    && (Restrictions.IsNull("ExpirationDate")
        || Restrictions.Ge("ExpirationDate", DateTime.Now)));
```

If you want to avoid the overloaded operators then you can use conjuction/disjunction to achieve the same affect (with a big increase in verbosity):

```
criteria.Add(Restrictions.Conjunction()
    .Add(Restrictions.Disjunction()
        .Add(Restrictions.IsNull("ShowOnDate"))
        .Add(Restrictions.Le("ShowOnDate", DateTime.Now))))
    .Add(Restrictions.Disjunction()
        .Add(Restrictions.IsNull("ExpirationDate"))
        .Add(Restrictions.Ge("ExpirationDate", DateTime.Now)))));
```

Comment: +1 didn't know about overloaded || &&. For this query, you could use the Restrictions.And and .Or instead. The Conjuction and Disjunction are for when you need to compare more than 2 expressions.

Comment: Perfect.  Awesome answer.  Thanks!  dotjoe, can you provide the a code sample of your suggestion?  I will upvote it.

Answer (score 2):

There is also Restrictions.And and Or for when you only need to combine two expressions...

```
criteria
    .Add(Restrictions.Or(Restrictions.IsNull("ShowOnDate"), Restrictions.Le("ShowOnDate", DateTime.Now)))
    .Add(Restrictions.Or(Restrictions.IsNull("ExpirationDate"), Restrictions.Ge("ExpirationDate", DateTime.Now)));
```

Comment: Newbie question - what's the difference between using Restrictions like you are and Expressions like I am in my OP?

Comment: Hibernate lists Expressions as semi-deprecated https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Expression.html but this is NHibernate so I'm not sure why?

Comment: Interesting.  I thought that Expressions were new and Restrictions were old.  I must have got that reversed.  I really need to learn a lot more...

Comment: dude tell me about...I've been using NHibernate for like 3 months and I keep learning new stuff every day.

Comment: We've been using it about the same duration.  I done a lot of "easy" stuff with it, but am just now starting to get a little more complex.

Comment: Yes me too...I think I learned it backwards because I had the dynamic Criteria queries down before I fully learned the mappings, cascades, change tracking, etc. Anyways, it sure beats the hell out of hand rolled data access!